# Problem while solving system of two second order non linear coupled differential equations using NDSolve function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am a completely new to *Mathematica*, and I am sorry if this question is dumb. I have to solve a system of two second order non linear coupled differential equations (that I got from the Lagrangian equation of motions for a particular system). The following is my code: I hope it is clear.

```
NDSolve[
 {
  -29.4 + 9.8 Cos[y[t]] + x[t] Derivative[1][y][t]^2 - 4 x''[t] == 0,   
  9.8 Sin[y[t]] + 2 Derivative[1][x][t] Derivative[1][y][t] + x[t] y''[t] == 0, 
  x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1.57, Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, 
  Derivative[1][y][0] == 29.4
 },
 {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0.1}
]
```

But I am getting exactly the same output as the input. *Mathematica* is returning the same piece of code.

Comment: I edited the code (it works now), please check if I got it right.

Comment: @b.gatessucks While correcting the code probably helped the poster, you have actually obscured the problem itself for the other readers. For cases like this it might be better to provide your insights in comments or as an actual answer.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Will do, thanks.

Comment: Dear ramanujan_dirac. I'd like to welcome you on Mathematica.SE. I would also like to ask you to solve the very basic questions (e.g., how to enter code into Mathematica, like you did below Verde's question) yourself using the quickstart guides that Mathematica provides. If you encounter any problems in that process, feel free to ask.

Comment: Also, please note that crossposting on other SE sites (like you did [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/solving-two-coupled-non-linear-second-order-differentially-equations-numerically)) is frowned upon. It scatters answers around and makes it more difficult for other users to find a complete answer.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Ok, I will keep that in mind. But I also wanted to know about other non Mathematica methods that I could use, the mathematica specific question was posted on this SE only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = NDSolve[{-29.4 + 9.8 Cos@y[t] +    x[t] y'[t]^2 - 4 x''[t] == 0, 
                     9.8 Sin@y[t] + 2 x'[t] y'[t]   + x[t]  y''[t] == 0,  
           x[0] == 1, y[0]  == 1.57, 
          x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 29.4}, 
         {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0.7}]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. s, {t, 0, .7}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

For the derivatives:

```
Plot[{x[t] /. s, Dt[x[t] /. s, t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh. How did you do this? Where do I enter the code actually? I myself entered it by create new -> package, and entered it in the input. Is this correct? Also, can I get a polynomial approximated function as the solution.

Comment: OK. I got it. Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: How can I get the graphs of x vs t, and y vs t?

Comment: OK. I tried this command Plot[Evaluate[x'[t]/.s],{t,0,.7}], with x prime replaced by x, for the x vs t graph and it worked. But it is not giving me an answer for x prime itself. The graph is blank.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac See edit. Please remember to upvote and accept answers, try also to answer questions, and read the faq of the site.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why did Dt work, and x' didnt work. I also tried plotting x''. In this case, Dt[Dt] didnt work, but x'' worked. +1 and accepted answer. But it would be good if you could answer the question, I posed in this comment.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac It is so because `s` is a replacement rule for `x[t]` but not for `x'[t]`. Try this `{x[t], x'[t]}/.s` to see how it works only in the first case.